# Google App Engine - Is it possible to start the jvm upon accessing an html page?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

I am currently building a (very) small website using Java and the Google App Engine. I know this website will never have more than 1 or 2 visits a day.

The problem I am facing is the very long (~7 seconds) first page loading. This is due from what I understand to the need to start a new Java virtual machine when the user first loads a page built from a jsp. I would like to avoid this user-unfriendly loading time.

For this small website, most of the pages can be static (i.e. only using html and css). There is just one page that needs to be dynamic (built from a jsp). Would it be possible to start the jvm when a user access an html page so that it is already running when he reaches the dynamic part of the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create some dummy endpoint (e.g. JSP returning just `OK` String) and call it after the static page is loaded using JavaScript. You can for example use following jQuery snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){ jQuery.get("/path/to/your/dynamic/dummy/page")})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

See [warmup requests](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Warmup_requests). The easiest would be to create a new servlet that performs similar function as the JSP page.